# Numerical method for solving equation with $u \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} + u$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I'm looking for a finite difference method to solve

$$a(x) u \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} + u = b(x)$$

where $u(0) = c$.

I tried to do a lagging convergence on the $u$ ie

$$a(x) u^{(n)} \frac{\mathrm{d}u^{(n+1)}}{\mathrm{d}x} + u^{(n+1)} = b(x)$$

But it was very slow to converge and the derivative is extremely noisy.

Are there better methods to solving this? I tried looking at Navier-Stokes literature but did not see anything.

Comment: It's a non-linear ODE, so you have three core approaches; use an explicit solver only, use an IMEX (implicit/explicit) scheme, or an iterative solver like Picard or Newton iteration.

Comment: What were the $a(x),b(x)$ functions you tested when you got slow convergence? Anyway this is a simple first order ODE so there are [plenty of methods to use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations). Why do you mention Navier-Stokes? I can't see any connection with that.

Comment: It is critical that you supply the functions $a, b$ and the interesting values of $c$. Otherwise, people will wonder why you can not simply divide the equation by $a(x)u(x)$ to bring it to standard form, i.e $u'(x) = f(u(x))$.

Comment: What do you mean by slow to converge exactly?